# What's the point of newtyping go interfaces instead of aliasing them?

Tags: go, type-conversion

In Go, interfaces are implemented by duck typing (or structurally typed). This means two interfaces types with identical signature are assignable to one another. For example,

```
type A interface {
    Foo()
}
type B interface {
    Foo()
}
```

We can use these two types interchangeably:

```
func expectsA(a A) {
    expectsB(a)
}

func expectsB(b B) {
    b.Foo()
}
```

This works because `A` contains all methods that `B` has. However, let's look at the disassembly of the program with these two functions (generated by `go tool compile -S` with go 1.17):

```
"".expectsA STEXT size=94 args=0x10 locals=0x20 funcid=0x0
    0x0000 00000 (b.go:24)  TEXT    "".expectsA(SB), ABIInternal, $32-16
    0x0000 00000 (b.go:24)  CMPQ    SP, 16(R14)
    0x0004 00004 (b.go:24)  PCDATA  $0, $-2
    0x0004 00004 (b.go:24)  JLS 67
    0x0006 00006 (b.go:24)  PCDATA  $0, $-1
    0x0006 00006 (b.go:24)  SUBQ    $32, SP
    0x000a 00010 (b.go:24)  MOVQ    BP, 24(SP)
    0x000f 00015 (b.go:24)  LEAQ    24(SP), BP
    0x0014 00020 (b.go:24)  MOVQ    AX, "".a+40(FP)
    0x0019 00025 (b.go:24)  MOVQ    BX, "".a+48(FP)
    0x001e 00030 (b.go:24)  FUNCDATA    $0, gclocals·09cf9819fc716118c209c2d2155a3632(SB)
    0x001e 00030 (b.go:24)  FUNCDATA    $1, gclocals·69c1753bd5f81501d95132d08af04464(SB)
    0x001e 00030 (b.go:24)  FUNCDATA    $5, "".expectsA.arginfo1(SB)
    0x001e 00030 (b.go:25)  MOVQ    BX, CX
    0x0021 00033 (b.go:25)  MOVQ    AX, BX
    0x0024 00036 (b.go:25)  LEAQ    type."".B(SB), AX
    0x002b 00043 (b.go:25)  PCDATA  $1, $1
    0x002b 00043 (b.go:25)  CALL    runtime.convI2I(SB)
    0x0030 00048 (<unknown line number>)    NOP
    0x0030 00048 (b.go:29)  MOVQ    24(AX), DX
    0x0034 00052 (b.go:29)  MOVQ    BX, AX

    0x0037 00055 (b.go:29)  CALL    DX
    0x0039 00057 (b.go:26)  MOVQ    24(SP), BP
    0x003e 00062 (b.go:26)  ADDQ    $32, SP
    0x0042 00066 (b.go:26)  RET
    0x0043 00067 (b.go:26)  NOP
    0x0043 00067 (b.go:24)  PCDATA  $1, $-1
    0x0043 00067 (b.go:24)  PCDATA  $0, $-2
    0x0043 00067 (b.go:24)  MOVQ    AX, 8(SP)
    0x0048 00072 (b.go:24)  MOVQ    BX, 16(SP)

    0x004d 00077 (b.go:24)  CALL    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
    0x0052 00082 (b.go:24)  MOVQ    8(SP), AX
    0x0057 00087 (b.go:24)  MOVQ    16(SP), BX
    0x005c 00092 (b.go:24)  PCDATA  $0, $-1
    0x005c 00092 (b.go:24)  JMP 0
    0x0000 49 3b 66 10 76 3d 48 83 ec 20 48 89 6c 24 18 48  I;f.v=H.. H.l$.H
    0x0010 8d 6c 24 18 48 89 44 24 28 48 89 5c 24 30 48 89  .l$.H.D$(H.\$0H.
    0x0020 d9 48 89 c3 48 8d 05 00 00 00 00 e8 00 00 00 00  .H..H...........
    0x0030 48 8b 50 18 48 89 d8 ff d2 48 8b 6c 24 18 48 83  H.P.H....H.l$.H.
    0x0040 c4 20 c3 48 89 44 24 08 48 89 5c 24 10 e8 00 00  . .H.D$.H.\$....
    0x0050 00 00 48 8b 44 24 08 48 8b 5c 24 10 eb a2        ..H.D$.H.\$...
    rel 2+0 t=25 type."".B+96
    rel 39+4 t=15 type."".B+0
    rel 44+4 t=7 runtime.convI2I+0
    rel 55+0 t=10 +0
    rel 78+4 t=7 runtime.morestack_noctxt+0
```

If I compile the same program with `type [AB] interface` (type definition) changed to `type [AB] = interface` (type alias), I get a different disassembly for `expectsA`. The following is a side-by-side comparison of the disassembly, where I align similar lines together. The left hand side is the type alias version, and the right hand side is the type definition version:

```
83  "".expectsA STEXT size=81 args=0x10 locals=0x10 funcid=0x0                                       │95  "".expectsA STEXT size=94 args=0x10 locals=0x20 funcid=0x0
  1         0x0000 00000 (a.go:24)  TEXT    "".expectsA(SB), ABIInternal, $16-16                     │  1         0x0000 00000 (b.go:24)  TEXT    "".expectsA(SB), ABIInternal, $32-16
  2         0x0000 00000 (a.go:24)  CMPQ    SP, 16(R14)                                              │  2         0x0000 00000 (b.go:24)  CMPQ    SP, 16(R14)
  3         0x0004 00004 (a.go:24)  PCDATA  $0, $-2                                                  │  3         0x0004 00004 (b.go:24)  PCDATA  $0, $-2
  4         0x0004 00004 (a.go:24)  JLS     49                                                       │  4         0x0004 00004 (b.go:24)  JLS     67
  5         0x0006 00006 (a.go:24)  PCDATA  $0, $-1                                                  │  5         0x0006 00006 (b.go:24)  PCDATA  $0, $-1
  6         0x0006 00006 (a.go:24)  SUBQ    $16, SP                                                  │  6         0x0006 00006 (b.go:24)  SUBQ    $32, SP
  7         0x000a 00010 (a.go:24)  MOVQ    BP, 8(SP)                                                │  7         0x000a 00010 (b.go:24)  MOVQ    BP, 24(SP)
  8         0x000f 00015 (a.go:24)  LEAQ    8(SP), BP                                                │  8         0x000f 00015 (b.go:24)  LEAQ    24(SP), BP
  9         0x0014 00020 (a.go:24)  MOVQ    AX, "".a+24(FP)                                          │  9         0x0014 00020 (b.go:24)  MOVQ    AX, "".a+40(FP)
 10         0x0019 00025 (a.go:24)  MOVQ    BX, "".a+32(FP)                                          │ 10         0x0019 00025 (b.go:24)  MOVQ    BX, "".a+48(FP)
 11         0x001e 00030 (a.go:24)  FUNCDATA        $0, gclocals·09cf9819fc716118c209c2d2155a3632(SB)│ 11         0x001e 00030 (b.go:24)  FUNCDATA        $0, gclocals·09cf9819fc716118c209c2d2155a3632(SB)
 12         0x001e 00030 (a.go:24)  FUNCDATA        $1, gclocals·69c1753bd5f81501d95132d08af04464(SB)│ 12         0x001e 00030 (b.go:24)  FUNCDATA        $1, gclocals·69c1753bd5f81501d95132d08af04464(SB)
 13         0x001e 00030 (a.go:24)  FUNCDATA        $5, "".expectsA.arginfo1(SB)                     │ 13         0x001e 00030 (b.go:24)  FUNCDATA        $5, "".expectsA.arginfo1(SB)
 14                                                                                                  │ 14         0x001e 00030 (b.go:25)  MOVQ    BX, CX
 15                                                                                                  │ 15         0x0021 00033 (b.go:25)  MOVQ    AX, BX
 16                                                                                                  │ 16         0x0024 00036 (b.go:25)  LEAQ    type."".B(SB), AX
 17                                                                                                  │ 17         0x002b 00043 (b.go:25)  PCDATA  $1, $1
 18                                                                                                  │ 18         0x002b 00043 (b.go:25)  CALL    runtime.convI2I(SB)
 19         0x001e 00030 (<unknown line number>)    NOP                                              │ 19         0x0030 00048 (<unknown line number>)    NOP
 20         0x001e 00030 (a.go:25)  MOVQ    24(AX), CX                                               │ 20         0x0030 00048 (b.go:29)  MOVQ    24(AX), DX
 21         0x0022 00034 (a.go:29)  MOVQ    BX, AX                                                   │ 21         0x0034 00052 (b.go:29)  MOVQ    BX, AX
 22         0x0025 00037 (a.go:29)  PCDATA  $1, $1                                                   │ 22         
 23         0x0025 00037 (a.go:29)  CALL    CX                                                       │ 23         0x0037 00055 (b.go:29)  CALL    DX
 24         0x0027 00039 (a.go:26)  MOVQ    8(SP), BP                                                │ 24         0x0039 00057 (b.go:26)  MOVQ    24(SP), BP
 25         0x002c 00044 (a.go:26)  ADDQ    $16, SP                                                  │ 25         0x003e 00062 (b.go:26)  ADDQ    $32, SP
 26         0x0030 00048 (a.go:26)  RET                                                              │ 26         0x0042 00066 (b.go:26)  RET
 27         0x0031 00049 (a.go:26)  NOP                                                              │ 27         0x0043 00067 (b.go:26)  NOP
 28         0x0031 00049 (a.go:24)  PCDATA  $1, $-1                                                  │ 28         0x0043 00067 (b.go:24)  PCDATA  $1, $-1
 29         0x0031 00049 (a.go:24)  PCDATA  $0, $-2                                                  │ 29         0x0043 00067 (b.go:24)  PCDATA  $0, $-2  
 30         0x0031 00049 (a.go:24)  MOVQ    AX, 8(SP)                                                │ 30         0x0043 00067 (b.go:24)  MOVQ    AX, 8(SP) 
 31         0x0036 00054 (a.go:24)  MOVQ    BX, 16(SP)                                               │ 31         0x0048 00072 (b.go:24)  MOVQ    BX, 16(SP)
 32         0x003b 00059 (a.go:24)  NOP                                                              │ 32         
 33         0x0040 00064 (a.go:24)  CALL    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)                             │ 33         0x004d 00077 (b.go:24)  CALL    runtime.morestack_noctxt(SB)
 34         0x0045 00069 (a.go:24)  MOVQ    8(SP), AX                                                │ 34         0x0052 00082 (b.go:24)  MOVQ    8(SP), AX 
 35         0x004a 00074 (a.go:24)  MOVQ    16(SP), BX                                               │ 35         0x0057 00087 (b.go:24)  MOVQ    16(SP), BX
 36         0x004f 00079 (a.go:24)  PCDATA  $0, $-1                                                  │ 36         0x005c 00092 (b.go:24)  PCDATA  $0, $-1
 37         0x004f 00079 (a.go:24)  JMP     0                                                        │ 37         0x005c 00092 (b.go:24)  JMP     0
 38         0x0000 49 3b 66 10 76 2b 48 83 ec 10 48 89 6c 24 08 48  I;f.v+H...H.l$.H                 │ 38         0x0000 49 3b 66 10 76 3d 48 83 ec 20 48 89 6c 24 18 48  I;f.v=H.. H.l$.H
 39         0x0010 8d 6c 24 08 48 89 44 24 18 48 89 5c 24 20 48 8b  .l$.H.D$.H.\$ H.                 │ 39         0x0010 8d 6c 24 18 48 89 44 24 28 48 89 5c 24 30 48 89  .l$.H.D$(H.\$0H.
 40         0x0020 48 18 48 89 d8 ff d1 48 8b 6c 24 08 48 83 c4 10  H.H....H.l$.H...                 │ 40         0x0020 d9 48 89 c3 48 8d 05 00 00 00 00 e8 00 00 00 00  .H..H...........
 41         0x0030 c3 48 89 44 24 08 48 89 5c 24 10 0f 1f 44 00 00  .H.D$.H.\$...D..                 │ 41         0x0030 48 8b 50 18 48 89 d8 ff d2 48 8b 6c 24 18 48 83  H.P.H....H.l$.H.
 42         0x0040 e8 00 00 00 00 48 8b 44 24 08 48 8b 5c 24 10 eb  .....H.D$.H.\$..                 │ 42         0x0040 c4 20 c3 48 89 44 24 08 48 89 5c 24 10 e8 00 00  . .H.D$.H.\$....
 43         0x0050 af                                               .                                │ 43         0x0050 00 00 48 8b 44 24 08 48 8b 5c 24 10 eb a2        ..H.D$.H.\$...
 44         rel 2+0 t=25 type.interface { Foo() }+80                                                 │ 44         rel 2+0 t=25 type."".B+96
 45         rel 37+0 t=10 +0                                                                         │ 45         rel 39+4 t=15 type."".B+0
 46         rel 65+4 t=7 runtime.morestack_noctxt+0                                                  │ 46         rel 44+4 t=7 runtime.convI2I+0
 47                                                                                                  │ 47         rel 55+0 t=10 +0
 48                                                                                                  │ 48         rel 78+4 t=7 runtime.morestack_noctxt+0
```

We can see that the type definition version (right side) generates an extra function call:

```
0x001e 00030 (b.go:25)  MOVQ    BX, CX
0x0021 00033 (b.go:25)  MOVQ    AX, BX
0x0024 00036 (b.go:25)  LEAQ    type."".B(SB), AX
0x002b 00043 (b.go:25)  PCDATA  $1, $1
0x002b 00043 (b.go:25)  CALL    runtime.convI2I(SB)
```

It seems that this call intends to convert a value from `type."".A` to `type."".B`. This evidently does not occur on the type alias version (left side), where the types are represented as `type.interface { Foo() }` instead.

To conclude my findings, it appears that type definition involves the overhead of calling [`runtime.convI2I`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/9de1ac6ac2cad3871760d0aa288f5ca713afd0a6/src/runtime/iface.go#L435). I am unsure how expensive this call is (I don't know if `tab.inter` to `inter` is true), but this overhead seems unnecessary for a NOP that merely deals with type level information. This leads me to wondering, how much overhead does `runtime.convI2I` cause in this case? If it causes an overhead, why do we define interfaces as new types instead of type aliases, if they are just structurally typed anyway?

Comment: If type `A` and `B` hold the same methods, there's no need for both. One is enough, or use type alias. The 2 may exist because you might not want to import the declaring package (thus introducing an otherwise unnecessary dependency), or `A` may change in the future which you don't want for `B`.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I expect the reason is that the compiler doesn't perform this optimization either because no-one has gotten round to it, or the benefits are small in real programs. Has this caused a measurable efficiency loss in a real program that you've written, or are you just interested academically?

Comment: @PaulHankin just academically. The whole point of exploring this behaviour came from the original question - Go interfaces are structural typing, and newtype pattern makes no sense in structural typing at all.

Comment: @icza it is not an actual use case I found, but if it is one, it is most likely because of coincidence from two separate packages using the same signature.